# Windows Authentication issue in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am currently doing a Load Testing of a website using Jmeter. This website uses Windows authentication. Because of this, I need to pass login credentials to the server.

How do I configure JMeter to login to the server using windows authentication?

I came to know that for windows authentication we need to use Http Authorization manager above the Http Request element. 
This is the input I have given in Http Authorization manager

Base url: Website URL
username: Username 
password: password

I am still not able to resolve the issue. I would be great if someone could help me in resolving the above issue in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows authentication types you need to provide at least:

- for [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager): Domain
- for [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)):

  - Realm
  - Kerberos mechanism
  - Perform JAAS configuration in krb5.conf and jaas.conf files (both in /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for configuration details.

Comment: I'm lost. Can we use Jmeter HTTP Authorization Manager to login to TFS? Seems like I've tried all the variations possible...

Answer (score 0):

Add the sql_auth dll into the JRE\bin folder. This solves the problem and makes JMeter run the SQL Queries with integrated security